# accessing extermal class variables from pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, pthreads

I am making a program in C++ which requires me to use several classes and threads to work the problem at hand. Here is a simplified snip:

Main Class: initializes the `eth_controller` and the `pt_proc_data` and calls on to start the worker thread `StartParsePacket`.

```
class MFA_MAIN : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MFA_MAIN(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MFA_MAIN();
    private:
        Ui::MFA_MAINClass ui;
        eth_controller* eth;
        pt_proc_data *pd;
    }
    MFA_MAIN::MFA_MAIN(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        eth = new eth_controller(ui.txtStatus, ui.cmbEthernetPort);
        pd = new pt_proc_data(PSD, eth, this);
        pd->StartParsePacket(ui.txtStatus);
    }
```

At this stage the ethernet class in only initialized, so the `bool ok` is set to `false` indicating the device handler are not yet correctly setup:

```
class eth_controller : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    eth_controller(QPlainTextEdit * status, QComboBox* list);
    ~eth_controller();
    bool ok;
}
eth_controller::eth_controller(QPlainTextEdit * status, QComboBox* list)
{
    ok = false;
......
}
```

Worker Class: he will start a new `pthread` to start parsing. but first he checks the ok variable in the ethernet class was properly setup or not:

```
class pt_proc_data 
{
public:
    pt_proc_data(data_ty t, eth_controller *e, QObject *g);
    ~pt_proc_data();

    //thread
    void *doParsePacket();
    //thread heplers
    static void *hParsePacket(void* ctx);
    //thread starters
    void StartParsePacket(QPlainTextEdit *status);


 private:
        //plot bins
....
        //parsing tools
        eth_controller *eth;
        vector<S> PayQueue;
        QObject* ptr_gui;

    //thread control
    pthread_t threads[3];
    bool init[3];
    pthread_mutex_t PlotLock;
    pthread_mutex_t QueueLock;
    pthread_mutex_t ResetLock;
    pthread_mutex_t ToggleLock;
    data_ty _type;
    bool _running = false;
    bool _end = false;
    int _freq;
    ofstream fd;
    bool _log;
}

pt_proc_data::pt_proc_data(data_ty t, eth_controller *e, QObject* g)
{
    _type = t; eth = e; ptr_gui = g;
}
void pt_proc_data::StartParsePacket(QPlainTextEdit *status)
{
    int rc;
    if (pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, &pt_proc_data::hParsePacket, this)) {
        status->appendPlainText("StartParsePacket Error:unable to create thread");
        return;
    }
    return;
}
void *pt_proc_data::hParsePacket(void* ctx)
{
    pt_proc_data *context = static_cast<pt_proc_data*>(ctx);
    context->doParsePacket();
    delete context;
    return 0;
    //return ((pt_proc_data *)ctx)->doParsePacket();
}
void *pt_proc_data::doParsePacket()
{
    if (!eth->ok)
    {
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(ptr_gui, "setStatusText",
            Q_ARG(QString, "payload download: Device not setup correctly."));
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(ptr_gui, "setStatusText",
        Q_ARG(QString, "doParsePacket: started."));
.......
}
```

The threads are started properly. at this stage the device is not setup correctly, so the `doParsePacket()` should always have find `eth->ok = false` and complain about the device not being setup correctly. BUT if i launch the program 10 times, 4-5 times, it will find that the value of `eth->ok` is `true`!!!!!

I was wondering someone could tell me why this is the case. Thank you

Comment: Off topic, but important to know: Don't use pthread, it's not cross platform. Use `std::thread` from C++11.

Comment: You don't have protected access to `ok` with a mutex or similar?

Comment: Insufficient data. You need to prove that "at this stage the device" is always "not setup correctly". With multiple threads that are going on, perhaps whatever is responsible for "setup correctly" part manages to do its job before this particular thread gets in gear.

Comment: @Sam ok is set as true only when bool `eth_controller::connect()` is called, but I have not called it. I was only testing. but when I do the same process from the same thread.

if that was the case why is it correctly executing 6 out of 10 times

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ. its read-only and only changed when the "connect button" is pressed which checks to make sure no threads are running. In any case, I am not calling it as I was only trouble shooting

Comment: @ The Quantum Physicist: thanks I though you have a pthread lib for linux and armv9.

Comment: The code in incomplete. In the `pt_proc_data` constructor, you assign to several variables which haven't been declared anywhere.

Comment: @ MuertoExcobito: they are declared as private variables. class, added them in the code

Comment: @Sam i set up a breakpoint in the code at the only place where 'ok' is set to true, and I never go there!!

Answer (score 0):

ok. I found a solution. I made the declaration of `bool ok;` as `private` and added a `bool isOk() {return ok;};` and it seem to be working now.

But I donot understand why this happened. maybe someone can shed some light